# Sorting Gridview When In Edit Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application I am sorting the gridview and also have Edit in that gridview, sorting works fine but when i click Edit, it puts the gridview in the original sorted order. when i click Edit - it lets me edit the row but it changes the order and show me the original record on that row in the edit mode.

```
private void LoadGridview()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            if (Session["sortedGV"] == null )
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spManagement_GetStationProfile", cs);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Que", ddlQue.SelectedValue);
                da.Fill(ds);
                dt = ds.Tables[0];

                Session["sortedGV"] = new DataView(dt);
            }
        }
        gvStations.DataSource = Session["sortedGV"];
        gvStations.DataBind();
    }

protected void gvStations_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {
                //This enables the EditTemplate
                int rowindex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
                gvStations.EditIndex = rowindex; //Enables the edit row in gridview                        
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "CancelUpdate")
            {
                gvStations.EditIndex = -1;
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
            {
                //DO SOME STUFF///
                gvStations.EditIndex = -1; //Takes you out of update view      
            }

            if ((DataTable)Session["sortedGV"] != null)
            {                    
                gvStations.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["sortedGV"];
            }
            else
            {
                gvStations.DataSource = LoadGridview();
            }
            gvStations.DataBind();
            btnAddStation.Visible = true;
  }
  private void SortGridview(string sortExpression, string Direction)
    {
        DataView dv = null;
        DataTable dt = gvStations.DataSource as DataTable;
        dv = new DataView(dt);

        dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + Direction;
        Session["sortedGV"] = dt;
        gvStations.DataSource = dv;
        gvStations.DataBind();

    }

    //Sorts gridview
    protected void gvStations_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        String sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        Session["SortExpression"] = sortExpression;

        if (Session["SortDirection"] != null && Session["SortDirection"].ToString() == SortDirection.Descending.ToString())
        {
            Session["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridview(sortExpression, "ASC");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridview(sortExpression, "DESC");
        }

    }
```

Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStations" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="StationID"
            Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
            OnRowCommand="gvStations_RowCommand" OnSorting="gvStations_Sorting">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="EditRow"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StationId")%>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="UpdateRow"
                            ForeColor="White" Text="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StationId")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="CancelUpdate"
                            ForeColor="White" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StationId")%>' Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StationID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="StationID"
                    Visible="false" ReadOnly="true">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <%--Station Number--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#" SortExpression="StationNumber">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbStationNumberEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StationNumber") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbStationNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StationNumber") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>  
          </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What happens when you move the data binding code in gvStations_RowCommand to the top or remove it all together?

Comment: IT sorts fine. But when I click Edit it sorts back to Ascending instead of keeping the Descending order.

Comment: Can you post the GridView markup so that I can set this up myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the DataView in the session and use it.  Not the DataTable.  The following modification makes the code work.  Also note that the Sort command runs in the RowCommand method first and then invokes your Sorting method so it's best to data bind explicitly for each command in the RowCommand event method.

```
    private string SortExpression
    {
        get { return (string) Session["SortExpression"]; }
        set { Session["SortExpression"] = value; }
    }

    private string Direction
    {
        get { return (string)Session["SortDirection"]; }
        set { Session["SortDirection"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGridview();
        }
    }

    protected void gvStations_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
        {
            //This enables the EditTemplate
            int rowindex = ((GridViewRow) ((LinkButton) e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            gvStations.EditIndex = rowindex; //Enables the edit row in gridview      

            LoadGridview();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "CancelUpdate")
        {
            gvStations.EditIndex = -1;
            LoadGridview();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
        {
            var dataView = (DataView) Session["sortedGV"];


            //DO SOME STUFF///
            gvStations.EditIndex = -1; //Takes you out of update view     


            LoadGridview();
        }
    }

    private void LoadGridview()
    {
        if (Session["sortedGV"] == null)
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("StationId", typeof (int));
            table.Columns.Add("StationNumber", typeof (string));
            DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
            row1["StationId"] = 1;
            row1["StationNumber"] = "343";
            table.Rows.Add(row1);

            DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
            row2["StationId"] = 2;
            row2["StationNumber"] = "443";
            table.Rows.Add(row2);

            Session["sortedGV"] = new DataView(table);
            SortGrid();
        }


        gvStations.DataSource = Session["sortedGV"];
        gvStations.DataBind();
    }


    private void SortGrid()
    {
        var dv = (DataView) Session["sortedGV"];
        if (SortExpression != null)
        {
            dv.Sort = SortExpression + " " + Direction;

        }
    }


    //Sorts gridview
    protected void gvStations_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SortExpression = e.SortExpression;

        if (SortExpression != null &&
            Direction == SortDirection.Descending.ToString())
        {
            Direction = "ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            Direction = "DESC";       
        }
        SortGrid();
        LoadGridview();
    }
```

Comment: This works but when you hit update it sorts it back to the original order.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.  Are you sure you copied the changes over correctly?

Comment: Actually it does keep the order but it does not refresh the data. I have to reload the page so the changes take effect.

Comment: I added my Loadgridview()

Comment: I was about to ask you to do that.  And you are saying that made it work?  Or it still doesn't?

Comment: I believe once I hit the update button it updates the data and it keeps the same order DESC or ASC which ever one it was. But since the data updated is not in the Session["sortedGV"] I have to hit that original storeprocedure so it can display the updated data. But I still haven't got it to work.

Comment: Add Session["sortedGV"] = null right before you call LoadGridvew() so that it gets a fresh copy of the data.

Comment: Yes, I did that earlier but it will put the gridview to its original state. If I had it in DESC and update it, it will put it back to ASC after the update.

Comment: You need to save the sort expression and direction in the view state so you can recreate the DataView when you have a new DataTable.  See modified code.

Comment: You have Session["SortExpression"] in the method gvStations_Sorting but in the private string SortExpression you have it as ViewState["SortExpression"]. Also the SortDirection.Ascending wont work since there is private string SortDirection. Am I missing something

Comment: I missed that you were already storing that in the session.  Check out the new changes.  Works on my end.

Comment: I made a few small changes and it works perfectly. Thanks for your patience and help.